# Linking hardware library

Tags: visual-c++

I just recently bought some hardware that came with a header file and object file library (The hardware is NI USB-6008 DAQ Card). I want to link the library to my current project in visual C++. I have included the header file, but how do I link the library that came with the hardware to the project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using Visual Studio and the library has come compiled already. Right click your program under solution explorer, select properties and under the Configuration Properties, select Linker then Input. You should see a field called Additional Dependencies in which you can add the `.a` or `.lib` file. The settings look like the below.[image] You can also link in the source files (only Visual Studio can do this as far as I am aware) by typing `#pragma comment (lib, "yourlibraryfilehere.lib")` This method only works if the `.a` or `.lib` file is in Visual Studio's `/lib/` directory.

Comment: for the #pragma route, do I need to have the .lib file in a particular directory?

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer to reflect that. It has to be in the Visual Studio's default library directory. You can change it in the settings but I don't recommend it. Instead just copy the `.lib` file into the default directory.

Comment: and with the other route, I just point to the .lib file under additional dependencies. If `#pragma` only works in visual studio, than what is the benefit of using it instead of just linking via Additional Dependencies which seems to be easier/less time consuming?

Comment: I think it might be easier for people to understand what libraries are being used from a glance and pinpoint errors rather than digging through the configuration. It also makes the code more portable from app to app because you don't have to reconfigure all the libraries. When you work with 10+ libraries that have to be linked, `#pragma` is easier. In the end the settings and `#pragma` method have the same performance. `#pragma` is a preprocessor so the compiler interprets it as a setting. More here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7(v=vs.71).aspx)